# SQL How to get Player VS Player Game Count from a Games in a Relational Database

Tags: sql, select

I am programming an application to keep score for darts. I've created a relational database as the following:

GameInformation
gameId | numberOfPlayer | totalInnings | gameType
0      |       2        |      13      |    0
1      |       2        |      14      |    0
2      |       2        |      20      |    0
3      |       3        |      16      |    0

PlayersByGame
gameId | playerId | innings | mpr
0      |     0    |    13   | 1.538
0      |     1    |    13   | 1.651
1      |     0    |    14   | 1.500
1      |     1    |    14   | 2.012
2      |     0    |    20   | 1.658
2      |     2    |    20   | 2.123
3      |     2    |    16   | 2.001
3      |     1    |    16   | 1.325
3      |     0    |    16   | 1.001

Players
Name      |   Id
Dainon    |   0
Andy      |   1
Keith     |   2

I'm familiar with simple SQL queries but and not sure how to get the number of games played by a player (Dainon) who played against a player (Andy) without the games that have more than 2 players and where only Dainon and Andy played against each other. At the time of the query, I have both Dainon and Andy's player IDs.

Could anyone provide any insight as to how I write a SELECT statement to do that.

I've started with wrong queries such as the following:

```
SELECT * FROM PlayersByGame WHERE playerId LIKE 0 and playerId LIKE 1;


SELECT gameId, numberOfPlayers, totalInnings, gameType
FROM GameInformation
WHERE (numberOfPlayers = 2)
UNION
SELECT gameId, playerId, innings, mpr
FROM PlayersByGame
WHERE (playerId = 0)
UNION
SELECT gameId, playerId, innings, mpr
FROM PlayersByGame AS PlayersByGame_1
WHERE (playerId = 1)
```

Thank you, I appreciate any of your assistance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.
Click her for [Sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/19bc5/14) version of it

```
select count(*) as NumOfGames
from
(
select gameid,count(*)
from 
(
    select gameId,playerId
    from PlayersByGame
    where gameId in
    (
        SELECT gameId from GameInformation
        where numberOfPlayer =2
    )
    AND
    playerId in
    (
        select id from Players
        where Name in('Dainon','Andy')
    ) 
) as A
group by A.gameId
having count(*) =2
) as B
```

Comment: Nico, That worked nicely!

The exact tested SQL SELECT statement is as follows:

SELECT COUNT(gi.gameId) AS Expr1
FROM GameInformation AS gi INNER JOIN
PlayersByGame AS pbg1 ON pbg1.gameId = gi.gameId AND pbg1.playerId = 0
INNER JOIN PlayersByGame AS pbg2 ON pbg2.gameId = gi.gameId AND pbg2.playerId = 1
WHERE (gi.numberOfPlayers = 2)

Answer (score 1):

I would try something like that (not tested)

```
SELECT count(gi.id)
FROM GameInformation gi
JOIN PlayersByGame pbg1 ON pbg1.gameId=gi.id AND pbg1.playerId = {idPlayer1}
JOIN PlayersByGame pbg2 ON pbg2.gameId=gi.id AND pbg2.playerId = {idPlayer2}
WHERE gi.numberOfPlayer = 2
```

Comment: Nico, That worked nicely!

The exact tested SQL SELECT statement is as follows:

SELECT COUNT(gi.gameId) AS Expr1
FROM GameInformation AS gi INNER JOIN
PlayersByGame AS pbg1 ON pbg1.gameId = gi.gameId AND pbg1.playerId = 0
INNER JOIN PlayersByGame AS pbg2 ON pbg2.gameId = gi.gameId AND pbg2.playerId = 1
WHERE (gi.numberOfPlayers = 2)